# What is subscription in reactive programming

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am trying to learn reactive programming, and I'm very confused about the word subscription.

What is a subscription in reactive programming?

I know that a subscriber will be created when I subscribe it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subscription is a connection between Subscriber and Publisher. Basically, Publisher will create a subscription for every Subscriber which will try to subscribe to it, and this subscription will handle requests from the subscriber. Publisher act as the storage of data and subscription will obtain data from it. I propose to you to go through http://www.reactive-streams.org/

Although, in my opinion, you can start here: http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html This is a better explanation of reactive data handling.